# Какие существуют алгоритмы предсказания перемещения объекта в онлайн игре?

Tags: android, алгоритм, 3d

Нужны алгоритимы по предсказанию поведения объекта. Данные об объекте будут передаваться через протокол, если вдруг пакеты будут потеряны на некоторое время , чтобы  смогли предсказать следующее движение.

Comment: Да обычная экстраполяция. Любое более "умное" предсказание будет основано на особенностях поведения конкретного объекта (например, конкретный объект никогда не поворачивает налево более 2 раз подряд) - а это уже индивидуальный, а не общий, алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Как было указано ранее, это индивидуально для каждого объекта. Можете обучить нейросеть - сложно и долго. Можно применить теорию игр, по крайней мере действия будут правильными. Ну и самый простой вариант зацикливание последних действий.